# how to embedd assets in flashbuilder

Tags: flash-builder, assets, embedded-resource

I have this air application where I want to add a swf file o the assets folder and then be able to define it in my mxml file, what is the correct way to do this so that the added swf file is included in the air instalation package? Will it automatically be included if I just add it to my assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you embed the assets with the [Embed] tag the assets will be included in the application during the compilation and you don't need to include it separately in the build package settings. Basically you only need to include the files into your build manually if you want to load them at runtime. For example,if you have some images in your assets folder that you want to LOAD (not embed) at runtime then you would need to include the assets folder into the build so that they're there when the application is running on the client.

You can embed whole swfs:

```
[Embed(source="mySWF.swf")] 
public var mySwfClass:Class;
```

Or just some symbols from a swf:

```
[Embed(source='mySWF.swf', symbol='mySymbolLinkageName')] 
public var mySwfClass:Class;
```

Remember that for the symbols you have to assign a linkage name to that symbol (and maybe mark it as "Export for actionscript" - don't remember if you really need to do that though)

Then you can declare your stuff like that:

```
// if your swf or swf symbol has multiple frames it will become a MovieClipAsset
var myMovieClip:MovieClipAsset = new mySwfClass() as MovieClipAsset;

// if it has only one frame it is a SpriteAsset:
var mySpriteAsset:SpriteAsset = new mySwfClass() as SpriteAsset;
```

If you are only working with MXML you often can pass the class to the components directly without casting and instantiation:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" label="Button" icon="{mySwfClass}" />
```